# Solving logarithmic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

I'm having problems with the resolution of this equation on $\lambda$:

$$\frac{(\lambda + 1)^2-2}{1+\lambda} = \ln \frac{(1+\lambda)^2}{2}.$$

What method can I do for solve that? Your hints are very welcome. Thanks a lot if you can help me.

Comment: You need to use numerical methods. A solution is $x=0.7064399904$

Comment: Textbook says that $\sqrt{2}-1$ is one solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's put $ \lambda+1=x $ then our equation becomes

> $$ \frac{x^2-2}{x} = \ln \frac{x^2}{2} \longrightarrow (*). $$

By inspection we can see that $x=\sqrt{2}$ makes both sides of $(*)$ equal $0$. That means

> $$x=\lambda +1 = \sqrt{2} \implies \lambda = \sqrt{2}-1. $$

Answer (score 1):

One method to find the solution:

1) observe that for $\lambda = 0$, we have that the LHS$ = -1$ and RHS$=-\ln 2$, so
LHS < RHS

2) for $\lambda=1$, we have LHS$=1$ and RHS$=\ln 2$, so LHS > RHS

3) because of the mean-value theorem, the solution of your problem $\lambda^*$ thus is between 0 and 1, $0< \lambda^* <1$.

4) divide the interval in half; observe that for $\lambda=1/2$, we have LHS > RHS

5) so, we have $0<\lambda^*<1/2$

6) repeat from step 4. every iteration reduces the size of the interval in which your solution is by 2. with this method, you can obtain the solution to your problem very fast to arbitrary accuracy.

Comment: In the textbook, solutions are $\sqrt{2}-1$ and $-\sqrt{2}-1$. I know this "hunting lion" method, but exact solutions exists.

Comment: Newton-Raphson converges much faster.